# call First LINQ method

Tags: vb.net, linq, expression-trees

I have this:

```
Dim aggregator_func As MethodInfo = Nothing
aggregator_func = GetType(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static).
    Where(Function(m) m.Name = "First").Where(Function(m) m.ReturnType.FullName = "")(0).MakeGenericMethod(GetType(Object))
Dim groupparameter = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Linq.IGrouping(Of Object(), Object())), "g")
Dim aggregation As Expression
```

I would like to call this: `g.First()(0)`

`g.First` returns an object array, but I need only the object at the specified index (in this case 0). I can easily provide the index with a constant, but how could I call the above expression?

I have googled, but found nothing useful to me.

This should be complement somehow:

```
aggregation = Expression.Call(aggregator_func, groupparameter)
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

The `g` parameter is an `Linq.IGrouping(Of Object(), Object())`. That' why `First` returns an array of objects. Maybe, an array of objects can be called an object too, but I think, this is not important now.

Comment: Since when does [First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx) return an array? It returns a single object

Comment: @dotnetom It will return array if you call it on a collection of arrays.

Comment: Take(1) ? Would that work on a collection

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek It will return a single object, which in case of collection of arrays happens to be an array. In the question it is stated that `g.First returns an object array`, which is incorrect, unless I don't know something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28195439/415661), static methods like `Enumerable.First` need a null instance passed as the first argument. You also need to construct the Generic Method `First` properly. If you don't, the compiler won't recognize the type of aggregation as `Object()`, rather just as `Object`, and it won't compile

Only line changed is the `aggregator_func` line, added last two lines.

```
    Dim aggregator_func As MethodInfo = Nothing
    aggregator_func = GetType(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static).
        Where(Function(m) m.Name = "First").Where(Function(m) m.ReturnType.FullName = "")(0).MakeGenericMethod(GetType(Object()))
    Dim groupparameter = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Linq.IGrouping(Of Object(), Object())), "g")
    Dim aggregation As Expression = Expression.Call(Nothing, aggregator_func, groupparameter)
    Dim arrayAccess As Expression = Expression.ArrayAccess(aggregation, Expression.Constant(0))
```

Comment: "static methods like Enumerable.First need a null instance passed as the first argument." Yes, I know this already. In this case - as I see - the focus was on Expression.ArrayAccess, which I have already used, but I don't get the idea to use it. And there was at the declaring of the First method Object() in the code, but I played around with the code, thus I changed it to Object. But with ArrayAccess it works now. Thanks.